# Linking SDL2 with CMake inside of CLion in Linux

Tags: c, linux, cmake, sdl, clion

I've been effortlessly trying to link SDL2 library to my CLion project. I've downloaded the `FindSDL2` script, but I'm still getting undefined reference to an SDL function.

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${project_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
project(SDL_Test C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(SDL_Test main.c)
target_link_libraries(SDL_Test ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

After trying to invoke `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` function I'm getting an `undefined reference` error:

```
[50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable SDL_Test
/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/main.c.o: in function `main':
/home/bartek/CLionProjects/SDL_Test/main.c:5: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/build.make:84: SDL_Test] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: SDL_Test] Error 2
```

Comment: That second line `set()` should come after the `project()` command, since [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) is defined by it (there's also a typo as it's not `project_SOURCE_DIR`).

Comment: @compor: [About the editing] Please, do format a build log as a **code**, not as a *citation*. With the latter formatting newlines are not preserved, and this breaks readability and understanding of the log. Also, `***` combination and `...' quoting are actual output of the compiler, do not change them.

Comment: @Fensi322: As noted by @compor, your setting of `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is wrong, so `find_package(SDL2)` doesn't use your `FindSDL2.cmake` script. As there is no error with that command, it uses some other script. Probably, it is `SDL2Config.cmake` script, shipped with the SDL2 itself. Please, show *configuration log* (when cmake is called). There should be lines about searching of SDL2 package.

Comment: @Tsyvarev [Blockquote](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp) is not a citation (there's an overlap in uses, but the meaning is different). There's a valid use of blockquote for one-liners, but you're right. What I dislike is the highlighting, but thanks for meta, there's a guideline [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286749/3048763). Can you please edit the question to fix that as suggested by the meta post? Lastly, I'm pretty sure that the `***` is Make output. I've never seen gcc/clang/ld/gold etc. output anything like that.

Comment: @compor: "Can you please edit the question to fix that as suggested by the meta post?" - Done. As for `***`, it is actually output of the Make, not of the compiler. What I meant by the previous comment, these starts are part of the actual build log, so they shouldn't be removed (as was in your edit which I have fixed).

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks all for help. It was first time I was using CMake.

Had to change every instance of "SDL2" to just SDL

Comment: wait no. I'm linking SDL1
`/bin/cc -g   CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/main.c.o  -o SDL_Test /usr/lib/libSDLmain.a /usr/lib/libSDL.so -lpthread `

but then I'm getting undefined reference to SDL_CreateWindow() function

when changing to as it was in question. I'm not linking anything so I think CMake cannot find SDL2
`/bin/cc -g   CMakeFiles/SDL_Test.dir/main.c.o  -o SDL_Test `

Comment: @Fensi322 if CMake could not find SDL2, it would fail during configuration since you have passed `REQUIRED` to `find_package`. Can you amend your question (*carefully*) with the build log when invoking `make VERBOSE=1` and can you print the SDL2 library variable using `message(STATUS "SDL libraries: ${SDL2_LIBRARY}")`?